# VirtualBox 6.1 and Kernel 5.8.0-34-generic

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I've installed the new `5.8.0-34-generic` kernel for `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` and `VirtualBox 6.1.10` stop working so I've installed the package found at `https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb` and it works, is this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfect solution.

VirtualBox from Ubuntu focal repos doesn't support the 5.8 kernel yet.

But you can get a `deb` from `virtualbox.org` site that supports the 5.8 kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. That was really helpful. I checked that Oracle did update the deb and the problem was only with the Ubuntu repos. Updated the answer. But you could give a hint about what was wrong.